# Android Room transactions across DAOs

Tags: android, sqlite, persistence, dao, android-room

The official documentation states that:

```
It is recommended to have multiple Dao classes in your codebase depending on the tables they touch.
```

and that one can mark a method with the Transaction annotation like that:

```
 @Dao
 public abstract class ProductDao {
    @Insert
     public abstract void insert(Product product);
    @Delete
     public abstract void delete(Product product);
    @Transaction
     public void insertAndDeleteInTransaction(Product newProduct, Product oldProduct) {
         // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
         insert(newProduct);
         delete(oldProduct);
     }
 }
```

But what if a transaction spans multiple DAOs? Should I merge all DAOs into one just to support transactions, or there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [RoomDatabase.runInTransaction(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#runInTransaction(java.lang.Runnable))

Something like:

```
database.runInTransaction(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    Access all your daos here
  }
});
```

Comment: Won't there be a problem with that each single insert, update or delete statement also runs in a transaction. You'll get nested transactions

Comment: No you cannot access DAOs here

Comment: @Vlad yes you can. You just need to have them injected to the wrapping class or added in different way

Answer (score 5):

**Fact 1:**
Using @Transaction on a method causes the method to be overriden in the Dao_Impl generated class. This method looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public void makeFieldInactive(final long fieldId) {
      __db.beginTransaction();
      try {
          MyDao_Impl.super.makeFieldInactive(fieldId);
          __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      } finally {
          __db.endTransaction();
      }
  }
```

**Fact 2:**
The runInTransaction() method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Executes the specified {@link Runnable} in a database transaction. The transaction will be
 * marked as successful unless an exception is thrown in the {@link Runnable}.
 * <p>
 * Room will only perform at most one transaction at a time.
 *
 * @param body The piece of code to execute.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void runInTransaction(@NonNull Runnable body) {
    beginTransaction();
    try {
        body.run();
        setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        endTransaction();
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**
They both do the same thing.

**More Info:**
I have done some testing and it appears that using either of them (or both, redundantly) will successfully cause your you Dao method to run in one transaction.

**Answer:**
Using @Transaction on a method that makes changes in multiple Daos that access the same database is a safe way to make sure that all database operations that happen in the method occur in one transaction.

**Edit:
Example of accessing multipe Dao's in one method marked with** @Transactoin:

```
@Transaction
 public void addItem(ItemEntity item) {
        item.setId(insert(item));
        ItemReportDao itemReportDao = AppDatabase.getIntance().itemReportDao();
        itemReportDao.addItemReport(item.getId());
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the "@Transaction on a method that makes changes in multiple Daos that access the same database"? Do you mark code outside of the "@Dao" with @Transaction and Room successfully generated the code?

Comment: The "@Transaction" annotation has to be within one of the abstract classes marked "@Dao".  The method marked "@Transaction" can then use multiple "@Dao" classes from within the "@Dao" class it is contained in. (interfaces marked "@Dao" must be converted to abstract classes in order to contain methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass reference to dao like parameter of funtion.