# Annotation (@Transaction) in Room Android not Work

Tags: java, android, android-room

I use ROOM with SQLite.

I have 2 entities:

**Weight**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = TABLE_WEIGHTING,
    foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(entity = CowDbEntity.class,
                    parentColumns = COW_COLUMN_ID,
                    childColumns = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_COW_ID,
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    }
)
public class WeightingDbEntity {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_NUM, defaultValue = "0")
private int num;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_COW_ID)
private int cowId;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_FIXED_WEIGHT)
private float fixedWeight;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_WEIGHT_GAIN, defaultValue = "0")
private float weightGain;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_PREV_RECORD, defaultValue = "0")
private int prevRecord;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_DATE)
private String date;

@ColumnInfo(name = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_WEIGHT_SERVER_ID, defaultValue = "0")
private int idWeightServer;
```

...

And **Comment**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = TABLE_COMMENT,
    foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(entity = WeightingDbEntity.class,
            parentColumns = WEIGHTING_COLUMN_ID,
            childColumns = COMMENT_COLUMN_WEIGHTING_ID,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    } 
) 
public class CommentDbEntity {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = COMMENT_COLUMN_ID)
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = COMMENT_COLUMN_WEIGHTING_ID)
private int weightingId;

private String description;

public CommentDbEntity(int weightingId, String description) {
    this.weightingId = weightingId;
    this.description = description;
}
```

...

I also use DAO:

for **Weight**

```
@Dao
public interface WeightingDao { 

@Insert
long insert(WeightingDbEntity weighting);
```

...

And DAO Comment:

```
@Dao
public interface CommentDao {

@Insert
long insert(CommentDbEntity comment);
```

...

I have a problem. I need to do something similar to this:

```
 @Transaction
insertWeightAndCow(CowDbEntity cow, CommentDbEntity comment) {
    insert(weighting);
    insert(comment);
}
```

**I need 2 queries to be executed only together. To do this, I will use @Transaction.
But the queries are in different classes. I do not know how to do it better.**

I tried to do:

I created the service class:

```
public class DBCommonService {

private static final String TAG = DBCommonService.class.getName();

private final WeightingDao weightingDao;
private final CommentDao commentDao;
private final CowDao cowDao;
private final HistoryDao historyDao;
private final ActionDao actionDao;

public DBCommonService(WeightingDao weightingDao, CommentDao commentDao, CowDao cowDao, HistoryDao historyDao, ActionDao actionDao) {
    this.weightingDao = weightingDao;
    this.commentDao = commentDao;
    this.cowDao = cowDao;
    this.historyDao = historyDao;
    this.actionDao = actionDao;
}

@Transaction
public long addWeightAndComment(WeightingDbEntity weighting, String comment) {

    try {
        long resAddWeight = weightingDao.insert(weighting);

        long resAddComment = 0;
        if(resAddWeight > 0) {
            resAddComment = commentDao.insert(new CommentDbEntity((int)resAddWeight, comment));
        }

        return resAddComment > 0 ? resAddWeight : 0;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

**But it doesn't work.** If I add you, and the comment is added with an error, there will be no rollback. And as a result, the weight will be added without comment. How to do it right?

PS:
A solution has been proposed here [Android Room transactions across DAOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164003/android-room-transactions-across-daos)

```
database.runInTransaction(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
Access all your daos here
  }
});
```

This solution is a void method, but I need a result for check (id record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the solution that worked (without @Transaction).

My service class:

```
public class DBCommonService {

private static final String TAG = DBCommonService.class.getName();

private final AppDatabase db;

public DBCommonService(AppDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;
}

public long addWeightAndComment(WeightingDbEntity weighting, String comment) {

    return db.runInTransaction(() -> {
        try {
            long resAddWeight = db.getWeightingDao().insert(weighting);

            long resAddComment = 0;
            if(resAddWeight > 0) {
                resAddComment = db.getCommentDao().insert(new CommentDbEntity((int)resAddWeight, comment));
            }

            return resAddComment > 0 ? resAddWeight : 0L;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return 0L;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately before or after the `@Transaction` annotation include the following:-

```
@Query("")
```

e.g.

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
insertWeightAndCow(CowDbEntity cow, CommentDbEntity comment) {
    insert(weighting);
    insert(comment);
}
```

Room then sees the function(s) as using the Database, due to the dummy query and wraps the function within a transaction (at least this used to be the behaviour).

This is according to https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Transaction, as per:-

> When used on a Query method that has a SELECT statement, the generated code for the Query will be run in a transaction. There are 2 main cases where you may want to do that:

> If the result of the query is fairly big, it is better to run it inside a transaction to receive a consistent result. Otherwise, if the query result does not fit into a single android.database.CursorWindow, the query result may be corrupted due to changes in the database in between cursor window swaps.

> If the result of the query is a POJO with {@link Relation} fields, these fields are queried separately. To receive consistent results between these queries, you also want to run them in a single transaction.

And then :-

> Putting this annotation on an Insert, Update or Delete method has no impact because those methods are always run inside a transaction. Similarly, if a method is annotated with Query but runs an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement, it is automatically wrapped in a transaction and this annotation has no effect. Room will only perform at most one transaction at a time, additional transactions are queued and executed on a first come, first serve order.

So the dummy query appears to fool Room into wrapping the otherwise ignored INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE (or whatever e.g. could be execSQL's, query or @Query annotated functions) into a Transaction.

And then

> The transaction will be marked as successful unless an exception is thrown in the method body.

Comment: Thank you for help (this is the second time :). Unfortunately this answer  did not help. It may not be possible to combine 2 inserts into one transaction.